# A java method which compares two strings and gives a boolean output if string2 can be made from the characters present in string1

Tags: java

I am trying to come up with a Java method where there are 2 string inputs and I get a boolean output if string2 can be made from all or some of the characters present in string1. Note that I am not just comparing 2 strings since that only works if the characters are in the same order.

This method also checks if the characters are present but not necessarily in the same order.

I understand that I have to use a loop to compare every character and probably sort the characters into an array but I am not clear on the logic for this.

I am thinking of using a for loop. Put the characters in the string as part of an array  and then compare the characters. And if the characters needed to make string 2 match the characters present in string 1 then the boolean result can just be true

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Imagine you had to do this with pen and paper.  How would you?  What logic would you use?  Now, can you encode that logic in Java?

Comment: *if string2 can be made from all or some of the characters present in string1*-what do you mean by **some of the characters** here?

Comment: One solution could be like if we find the permutation of the first string and then compare each string with the second string and if it matches fully or partially then we could return true.

Comment: One thing to consider - can you reuse characters from string1? That is, can you make "tact" from "cat"?

Comment: I am thinking of using a for loop. Put the characters in the string as part of an array  and then compare the characters. And if the characters needed to make string 2 match the characters present in string 1 then the boolean result can just be true

Comment: When i mean by some of the characters, I mean this example: String1 = computer string2 = mop. so not all the characters from string 1 were used to make string 2

Answer (score 0):

If you can reuse characters from String one use:

```
static boolean compare(String outer, String inner){
    int innerLength = inner.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < innerLength;i++){
        if(outer.indexOf(inner.substring(i,i+1))==-1){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you cannot reuse characters from String 1 then use:

```
static boolean compare(String outer, String inner){
    int innerLength = inner.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < innerLength;i++){
        int index = outer.indexOf(inner.substring(i,i+1));
        if(index==-1){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            outer = outer.substring(0,index)+outer.substring(index+1);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```